# Como mudar a cor das linhas de um JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Preciso que a cor da linha mude sempre que o valor da célula for igual a 0. No entanto, todas as linhas estão sendo pintadas.

View com um simples JTable

```
import javax.swing.JTable;

    public class View extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        private EstoqueActionListener listener;

        public View() {
            initComponents();
            this.listener = new EstoqueActionListener(this);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
        private void initComponents() {

            jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
            tableEstoque = new javax.swing.JTable();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            tableEstoque.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                new Object [][] {
                    {null, null},
                    {null, null},
                    {null, null},
                    {null, null}
                },
                new String [] {
                    "PRODUTO", "STATUS"
                }
            ));
            jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tableEstoque);

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 752, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 295, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            );

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>                        


        public static void main(String args[]) {

            try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(View.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(View.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(View.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(View.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new View().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        public JTable getTableEstoque() {
            return tableEstoque;
        }

        public void setTableEstoque(JTable tableEstoque) {
            this.tableEstoque = tableEstoque;
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
        private javax.swing.JTable tableEstoque;
        // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

Classe EstoqueTableModel que estende AbstractTableModel

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class EstoqueTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    List<Estoque> estoques;
    List<String> colunas = Arrays.asList("PRODUTO", "SALDO");

    public EstoqueTableModel() {
        Estoque e1 = new Estoque("ProdutoA", 10);
        Estoque e2 = new Estoque("ProdutoA", 10000);
        Estoque e3 = new Estoque("ProdutoA", 0);
        estoques = new ArrayList<>();
        estoques.add(e1);
        estoques.add(e2);
        estoques.add(e3);

    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return estoques.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return colunas.size();
    }

    public int getColumnIndex(String coluna) {
        return colunas.indexOf(coluna);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Estoque e = estoques.get(rowIndex);
        String columnName = getColumnName(columnIndex);
        switch(columnName) {
            case "PRODUTO": return e.getNomeProduto();
            case "SALDO": return e.getSaldo();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return colunas.get(column);
    }



    public List<Estoque> getEstoques() {
        return estoques;
    }

    public static class Estoque {
        private String nomeProduto;
        private int saldo;

        public Estoque(String nomeProduto, int saldo) {
            this.nomeProduto = nomeProduto;
            this.saldo = saldo;
        }

        public String getNomeProduto() {
            return nomeProduto;
        }

        public void setNomeProduto(String nomeProduto) {
            this.nomeProduto = nomeProduto;
        }

        public int getSaldo() {
            return saldo;
        }

        public void setSaldo(int saldo) {
            this.saldo = saldo;
        }
    }

}
```

Classe que gerencia os eventos da view e inicia os dados da JTable

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class EstoqueActionListener {

    private View viewEstoque;
    private EstoqueTableModel tableEstoque;

    public EstoqueActionListener(View viewEstoque) {
        this.viewEstoque = viewEstoque;
        startTable();
    }

    public void startTable() {
        tableEstoque = new EstoqueTableModel();
        if (tableEstoque.getEstoques() != null) {
            viewEstoque.getTableEstoque().setModel(tableEstoque);

            for (int i = 0; i < tableEstoque.getEstoques().size(); i++) {
                int cellValue = (int) tableEstoque.getValueAt(i, tableEstoque.getColumnIndex("SALDO"));
                if (cellValue == 0) { //SE 0, MUDE A COR
                    viewEstoque.getTableEstoque().setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
                        @Override
                        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                            final Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                            c.setBackground(Color.red);
                            c.setForeground(Color.white);
                            return c;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Até achei uma solução, mas sem um [mcve], não tem como nem eu testar no seu código pra ver se vai funcionar ou votar reabertura. Adicione isso na pergunta pra facilitar a reabertura.

Comment: Já tenho uma solução, só esperando reabrirem a pergunta.

Comment: @diegofm descobri por que naquele exemplo anterior nada estava sendo pintado. Dentro do método eu estava passando meu objeto para outra classe alinhar as células. Como uma nova instância do DefaultTableCellRenderer era criada, eu perdia as características da anterior. Isso eu já consertei, porém, todas as células são pintadas em vez daquelas específicas. Aguardo sua solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro é preciso entender o que a chamada abaixo significa:

```
viewEstoque.getTableEstoque().setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new 
                                    DefaultTableCellRenderer(){..});
```

Este método espera o tipo das células da tabela e um *renderer* que será aplicado as células com aquele tipo informado. Apesar de `Object`ser a classe-mãe de todas as classes em java, há uma peculiaridade no funcionamento dos renderers do swing, onde ele aplica determinada renderização conforme os tipos abaixo:

> - `Boolean` - renderiza com uma caixa de seleção(checkbox).
> - `Number` - renderiza um Label alinhado à direita.
> - `Double`, `Float`- o mesmo que Number, mas a conversão "objeto-to-text" é realizada por uma instância de `NumberFormat`(usando o formato de número padrão para a localidade atual).
> - `Date`- renderiza um Label, com a conversão de "objeto-to-text" realizada por uma instância de `DateFormat`(usando um estilo curto para a data e hora).
> - `ImageIcon`, `Icon`- renderizado com um Label centralizado.
> - `Object` - renderizado por um Label que exibe valor de string do objeto.

Como o valor da sua coluna `saldo` é do tipo numérica, ao renderizar, o java levará o tipo em consideração e aplicará a segunda opção da lista acima, ignorando completamente o que você definiu no renderer.

Para resolver isso, a forma mais simples consiste em definir um renderer diretamente pra coluna numérica, ao invés de aplicar a toda tabela:

```
// no lugar do "1" é preciso informar o indice da coluna desejada
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new SaldoTableRenderer());
```

Neste caso, optei por criar a classe `SaldoTableRenderer`, e nela precisamos salvar os valores do background e foreground padrão, pois quando o valor não for zero, você pode restaurar esses valores na célula seguinte:

```
public class SaldoTableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    Color defaultBackground, defaultForeground;

    public SaldoTableRenderer() {
        this.defaultBackground = getBackground();
        this.defaultForeground = getForeground();
        setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JLabel.RIGHT);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        final Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

            Integer saldo = (int) value;

            if (saldo == 0) {
                c.setBackground(Color.red);
                c.setForeground(Color.white);
            }else{
                c.setBackground(defaultBackground);
                c.setForeground(defaultForeground);             
            }
            setText(saldo.toString());

        return c;
    }

}
```

E o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso queira ver na prática antes de aplicar ao seu código, fiz um [exemplo testável](https://gist.github.com/diegofelipem/d2b21f3b08c1d7a5e636a8a9796ac94d), basta compilar.

---

Para que colora a linha toda, é preciso sobrescrever o método `prepareRenderer` da tabela, utilizando a mesma lógica do renderer anterior da resposta:

```
    table = new JTable(new EstoqueTableModel()) {
        @Override
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {

            final Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

            Integer saldo = (int) table.getValueAt(row, 1);

            if (saldo <= 0) {
                c.setBackground(Color.red);
                c.setForeground(Color.white);
            } else {
                c.setBackground(table.getBackground());
                c.setForeground(table.getForeground());
            }
            return c;
        }
    };
```

---

**Referências:**

[Concepts: Editors and Renderers(Documentação)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

Comment: Realmente ele pintou só as que tem o valor específico. Porém, pintou só a célula. Como posso pintar a row toda?

Comment: @MarceloAugusto sem modificar o seu tablemodel, não tem como fazer isso.

Comment: O que seria preciso modificar?

Comment: fiz uma pequena modificação no seu código. Peguei o valor do saldo a partir de table.getValueAt(row, 1). Assim consegui pintar.

Comment: @MarceloAugusto mudando o tipo da coluna para não numerico e aplicando o cellrenderer a toda a tabela. Teria que validar o valor de saldo pelo indice da coluna tambem.

Comment: @MarceloAugusto essa alteração apenas no código da resposta não resolve o problema. Tem que alterar o tipo da coluna salto tambem.

Comment: Na classe ColumnTableRenderer eu acrescentei um parâmetro que é a coluna cujo valor que deve ser comparado está. Assim, eu consigo pintar todas as linhas cujo saldo é 0. Isso resolveu meu problema.

Comment: @MarceloAugusto a resposta não lhe ajudou de nenhuma forma? Se sim, você pode marcá-la como aceita, clicando no `v` a esquerda. Desta forma, ela serve de referencia para outras pessoas com problema semelhante :)

Comment: Desculpe, cara. Depois que resolvi o problema como te falei, acabei esquecendo. Obrigado!